# Are there any pre-built binaries for Node.JS on Solaris?

Tags: node.js, build, solaris

I tried on a Solaris 11 machine and it works, I can even copy the built executables to the Solaris 10 machine.

When I try to build on Solaris 10 I get `Host architecture was not detected as supported by v8` which is weird because both machines are x86.

Getting to Solaris 11 is a hassle because I don't always have a Solaris 11 machine available. (like now) Usually I just have Solaris 10 6/06.

It seems there would be some pre-built binaries out there somewhere. Does anyone know of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.petertribble.co.uk/Solaris/node.html

http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/t/47680586592637f2

Comment: This is a good answer, the only thing lacking is that openssl is built in which kills the ability to move the install to an alternative directory. I contacted Peter, if he has time, I hope he will provide an alternative that uses the existing openssl.